# CM type of a CM field?

Tags: number-theory, extension-field

I am reading a paper by Colmez, it is titled - "Fonctions zeta p-adiques en s=0". It is completely in French and I am using Google translate to convert it. There is one line which Google translates in something which I couldn't make sense of.

Here's the line -

(in French) :- "Si K est un corps CM, un type CM de K sera par definition un sous-ensemble de $Hom(K,\overline{Q})$ tel que l'application de $\Sigma$ dans $S_{\infty}$ soit une bijecition"

translates to

(in English) :- "If K is a CM field, a CM type of K will be by definition  a subset of $Hom(K, \overline{Q})$ such that **the application of** $\Sigma$ in $S_{\infty}$ is a bijecition."

where $S_{\infty}$ is the set of all archimedean valuations on K and $\overline{Q}$ is algebraic closure of $Q$ (the rationals).

I don't understand what this application means?

Comment: *application* means *map*.

Comment: And here he's referring to the map from $\Sigma$ (the given subset of $\mathrm{Hom}(K, \overline{\mathbb Q})$) to $S_{\infty}$.  Let me add for future reference that Kai-Wen Lan's glossary (http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf) of French math words can be very helpful.

Comment: Applications aside: $\Sigma$ is a CM type (on the CM field $K$) iff there is a disjoint union $ \text{hom}(K,{\mathbb C})= \Sigma \cup  \iota \Sigma$, where $\iota$ is complex conjugation. See for instance http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1981dT.pdf